# need to change class in repeater elements

Tags: c#, html, dom, repeater

i have a repeater:

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" onitemcommand="Repeater4_ItemCommand"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <li class="sports_menu1">  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="selected  onclick="sideMenuSports1_Click"> 
    <%#Eval("iconURL")%> 
    </asp:LinkButton></li> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

and i want to handle all the buttons in the same function:

```
protected void sideMenuSports1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    changeDataSources();   /*-----> this function supose to derict to URL(in a div on the same page) acording the id  of the item of the repeater   */ 
    removeAllClasses();  /*this supose to remove all class named selected from the element in the <asp:button> element */
    ((LinkButton)sender).Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
}
```

to sumerise, what i need is:

1. i need to remove the class "selected" in all the repeater  `<asp:button>` elements, then add it only to the element the user clicked
2. each button clicked redirect to other URL ,how i pass the button the id of the repeater element?

Comment: do you pass id in url query parameter?

Comment: i have the id of the element in the sqlDataSource ,i can reach it in the html code inside the repeater by writing <#Eval("id")> but i don't want to display the id, i  need to pass it to a function that changes other part of the page.also i need a "selecetedID" to redirect to this page then add the class "selected" to the apropriate repeater element

Comment: why not remove default class="selected" from button and add it only when clicked?

Comment: its dynamic menu.the class need to change every time a user hits a button.if he press one button all other buttons need to loose that class and he stays in the same page.if i removed class="selected" from html ,i still have problem that the class is turned on but never turned off

Comment: The `LinkButton` control has `CssClass` property inherited from `WebControl`. Is there some reason you are not using that instead of adding as an attribute?

Comment: how i access the ccs class of the likbutton in the repeater?or i i access etement inside the repeate by class or tag?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved it like this:

**.aspx part:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemsRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="itemsRepeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton id="location_button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Key") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**code-behind part:**

```
protected void itemsRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // for the sample purpose, setting the value here - replace it with your own
    int locationId = 2;

    // looping through all the repeater items (buttons)
    foreach (RepeaterItem i in ((Repeater)source).Items)
    {
        // finding the repeater items having ID set to "location_button"
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)i.FindControl("location_button");

        // custom class added when location matches button's CommandArgument
        if (btn.CommandArgument == locationId.ToString())
            btn.CssClass = "button_main active";
        else
            btn.CssClass = "button_main";
    }
}
```